# Adding text to file in loop (Set-Content, Add-Content, Out-File?)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add content to a .txt file, but the results are overwritten when I use `Out-File`, and when I use `Add-Content` or `Set-Content` format is changed.

```
foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem .\Upload)) {
    Write-Host -Object "Uploading $item..."
    $Send = Add-FTPItem -Session $Session -Path $FTPPlace -LocalPath .\Upload\$item -Overwrite -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue #>> .\up.txt #.\Upload\test.txt
    if ($Send.Name -eq $item.Name) {
        $Rec = "OK"
    } else {
        $Rec = "!!!-FAIL-!!!"
    }
    $array = $line, $item, $connect, $Rec
    $FailTable = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
        "FTP Server" = $array[0];
        "File"       = $array[1];
        "Connected"  = $array[2];
        "Uploaded"   = $array[3]
    })
    $FailTable >> .\stats.txt
    #$FailTable | Set-Content .\stats.txt
    #Write-Output $FailTable | Add-Content .\stats.txt
    #Add-Content .\stats.txt $FailTable
    $FailTable | Out-File '.\stats.txt' #-NoClobber
}
```

Effect of working `Out-File`:

```
FTP Server   File     Connected Uploaded
----------   ----     --------- --------
10.80.59.170 test.txt OK        OK
```

and results of working `Set-Content` and `Add-Content`:

```
@{FTP Server=10.80.59.170; File=Config.xml; Connected=OK; Uploaded=OK}
@{FTP Server=10.80.59.170; File=test.txt; Connected=OK; Uploaded=OK}
```

Comment: You could also try to call `ToString()` on the object before writing it (effectively what `Out-File` seems to do.

Comment: Nice. And how to save headers "FTP Server" "File" Connected" "Uploaded" once with first iteration?

Comment: Just use the switch `-append` after the outfile.

Comment: Looks to me like what you *actually* want is `Export-Csv -Append`.

Comment: No. I want save in .txt, but how to write headers ("FTP Server" "File" Connected" "Uploaded" ) once and under status save uploads results (10.80.59.170 test.txt OK        OK )?

Comment: Umm... yes, that is exactly how appending to a CSV works.